# Set list vs Fixed list (of items)

Tags: difference, word-difference

In programming some components have a **set list of items** while others have a **fixed list of items**. Are both usages correct and outside of programming is there a difference between them?

How different are they from the "a list of items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of programming, the meanings between your two phrases are basically the same

> a **set** guest list
>   a **fixed** guest list
>
> a **set** price
>   a **fixed** price

are both lists and prices which have been determined beforehand and not changeable.  One might say

> The guest list is **set**.
>   The price is **set**.

which has a different meaning of being *established*. Whereas,

> The guest list is **fixed**.
>   The price is **fixed**.

has the same meaning of *unchangeability*.

The difference is in programming there is the particular concept of *immutability* where an array or list can not be changed programmatically and is usually a fundamental feature of a programming language, but in everyday usage the definitions can be more blurred and ambiguous which can not be allowed in programming.

Answer (score 1):

> a **set list** of items

A [*set*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set):

> 1. *countable noun*
>      A set of things is a number of things that belong together or that are thought of as a group.

So this list contains items that go together for some reason.

vs.

> a **fixed list** of items

See [*fixed*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fixed):

> 1. *adjective*
>      You use fixed to describe something which stays the same and does not or cannot vary.

So a fixed list never changes. All items stay the same.

And *a list* is just a list. That's all.

Comment: If we say "a set of items" instead of "a set list of items" will it change the meaning?

Comment: "a set of items" might be 5 actual bottles, while "a set list of items" is just a written list of them (Budweiser, Michelob ...).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with the others that the meanings are very similar, but, to me, have a slight nuanced difference.  A set list to me indicates that the what of the list is predetermined, while a fixed list indicates that both what and where are predetermined (the order of the list).